# Low PCA loadings (especially on PC1 and most others)

Tags: r, pca, prcomp

I have a set of 100 variables and aim to reduce my data dimension for further subsequent analyses. There are about 300 observations.

Upon `prcomp()` in R (with `retx= TRUE`), my PC1's loadings (abs) are all below 0.20. And, most other PCs' loadings (abs) are also in the range of 0.01-0.30.

How would you do in this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you scale the data before PCA. If you don't then the loadings can get skewed. Set the `scale` variable in prcomp to 'TRUE'.

Comment: Don't forget the dot: `scale. = TRUE`

Comment: Yes, I have. My code looks like this: 
prcomp((pca.data[,202:304]^(1/3)), center= T, scale=T,retx= T). None of my PCA loadings is greater than 0.20.